# opengl copying textures is skewing the textures

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, render-to-texture

I'm copying a texture from a framebuffer to an empty texture using

```
float *temp = new float[width*height*4];
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbTex2);
glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, temp);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, colour_map_tex);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA32F, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, temp);
```

(yes I tried `glCopyImageSubData()` and it didn't work)

and `colour_map_tex` is initialized as

```
glGenTextures(1,&colour_map_tex);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, colour_map_tex);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST); 
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST); 
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA,width,height,0,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,NULL);
```

this is then used to hold a colour map (everything drawn but using a single colour for each object/mesh) which is drawn to a frame buffer and then used to make a mask.

but the issue is when I use the mask, everything is aligned ie. the mask and the texture it is masking are lined up, but when I move the camera around the translations are slightly different which results in the masked image being really skewed in relation to the actual scene.

so my questions are, is there anything that is likely to be the cause of the skewing? or anything that can be done to fix it? would a 3rd frame buffer be a better idea instead of copying the data to an empty texture? and if so why?

overview of what is happening :
 1. whole scene is being rendered with textures to a framebuffer. 
 2. whole scene is rendered a second time without textures but each mesh has a colour associated with it, this is rendered to a second framebuffer and is for a mask.
 3. the mask texture is copied to an empty texture 
 4. the texture from the first frame buffer is drawn onto a plane the size of the viewport ( drawn to the second framebuffer)
 5. the mask is overlayed onto the plane to mask out parts of the texture (drawn to the second view buffer)
 6. the texture from the first frame buffer is drawn on to a plane the size of the viewport, this time drawn to the screen 
 7. there is an optional post processed image generated from the texture in the second frame buffer. which is semi transparent and drawn over the rendering of the scene.

I havent posted the whole display function because its pretty big but I'm happy to post more if there is a specific bit that you want.

Comment: You could also blit the contents of your original framebuffer into an attachment of another framebuffer and avoid copying image data from the server to client and then back to server. Blitting is usually slightly slower than drawing a textured quad, but if you don't want to be bothered with using textures, it can be helpful.

Comment: Also, if you set the read buffer to your framebuffer's color attachment, you can copy the framebuffer image directly to a texture using `glCopyTexSubImage2D (...)`. This avoids the server->client copy mentioned before and does server->server.

Comment: I did consider blitting but the parts of the textures that I want to omit are not a uniform colour or even a distinct range, which was why I went for the mask instead. I have no aversion to using textures, I just want them to not be skewed when I need them.   That is what I was trying to do with `glCopyTextSubImage2D()` but it kept giving me a blank texture

Comment: Really? Because your question suggests you were trying to use `glCopyImageSubData (...)`, which is quite different from `glCopyTexSubImage2D (...)`.

Comment: oh, apologies I misread the function. I'll give `glCopyTextSubImage2D()` a try and see if it helps